# How to shim property being set on a 3rd party external dll

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dll, shim

I am working on writing a unit test for the following function..

```
public virtual FacadeClass InitNewAMSObject()
{
    FacadeClass output = null;

    if (ClassMapInfo != null)
    {
        // Override the metadata caching option
        // sets property in external dll
        Avectra.netForum.Common.Config.CacheMetaData = false;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ClassMapInfo.AMSClassName))
        {
            output = DataUtils.InstantiateFacadeObject(ClassMapInfo.AMSClassName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new System.ApplicationException("Need to add the attribute");
    }

    return output;
}
```

I cannot get past the line with the comment "sets property in external dll".  My shim never seems to 'make it over' to the function being tested. It always throws an error, and its actually trying to use the dll instead of my shim. It may look like i'm setting a property to false only, but the dll uses the property like a method in it's Setter. The .Config is always in an errored state because its constructors (in the dll) are attempting to set up database connections. I expect it to be in at least a null state, and also have the .Fakes. in the class name.  I just want to skip over it because I do not write this dll, its 3rd party.

I've researched for a day now and cannot find an example anywhere of how to shim a property that is set on a referenced dll.

Here is my current test for what its worth

```
[TestMethod]
        public void InitNewAMSObjectTEST()
        {
            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {

                Address amsc = new Address();

                bool test = true;

                ShimConfig.CacheMetaDataGet = () => test;
                ShimConfig.CacheMetaDataSetBoolean = value => test = value;

                amsc.InitNewAMSObject();

            }

        }
```

Comment: Will encapsulating the `Avectra.netForum.Common.Config.CacheMetaData = false;` in a static method and shim that method work?

Comment: It doesn't look like a `get` call to me, but rather a `set` call. Might want to shim that as well. As in, `ShimConfig.CacheMetadataSet = value => test = value;`

Comment: Screenshot of the debugger in action showing the shim not working. http://assets.nursingsociety.org.s3.amazonaws.com/shimz.jpg

Comment: Since you are just setting hardcoded to false, just remove all the shims for CacheMetaData. Why do you want to fake that?

Comment: The dll is not written all that well. The property's setter acts like a method.